# How to I vertically center the title of my rmarkdown pdf document?

Tags: r-markdown, pdflatex

I have the following preamble:

```
---
title: "Luke Klein Dissertation MARKDOWN ROUGH DRAFT"
author: "Luke KLEIN"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
---
```

How do I get my title centered on the cover page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably already finished your dissertation :-) but leaving the solution for future reference as i came here through google.

```
---
title: |
  | \vspace{5cm} \LARGE{Luke Klein Dissertation MARKDOWN ROUGH DRAFT}
author: "Luke KLEIN"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
pdf_document:
  toc: true
---
```

Using a combination of vspace and hspace you can put the title anywhere you want.

Other combinations of fonts (both size and type) can be seen here:

https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Font_sizes,_families,_and_styles?nocdn=true

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, this worked for me :

```
---
title: "Luke Klein Dissertation MARKDOWN ROUGH DRAFT"
author: "Luke KLEIN"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
pdf_document:
  toc: true
header-includes:
- \pretitle{\begin{center} \vspace{5cm}}
---
```